# Qlikview Update, append without delete from weekly list

Tags: qlikview

I have tables List1 (9000+/- records) and List2 (9500 records+/-) with the fields;

episodenum (PrimaryKey)
ArchiveDate (Unique to each list)
Data(Multiple fields)

I wish to join the tables each week, retaining

- Records present in List1 but not present in List2, clasified as status 'OffList',Data as per List1,
- Records present in List1 and List2 classified as status 'OnList', Data as per List2,
- Records present in List2 not present in List1 classified as status 'NewToList', Data as per List2 (See attached Diagram)[List1 and List2 and desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JR4y.png)

This is a simple enough matter in Sql, but the automatic join that occurs in the Qlikview load has me stumped.

I wish to reduce the number of records loaded as the table will build over time when 'OffList' records are retained, and in order to be able to use simple count expressions rather than the selections and set analysis required when the full set of records is loaded and combined.

Is there a simple method of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

As you were so kind providing an example, I'll leave you with a script using the same data :

```
Data:
LOAD * INLINE [
    X, Y
    1, A1
    2, A2
    3, A3
];

Left Join (Data)
LOAD
    X, 
    Y as NewY;
LOAD * INLINE [
    X, Y
    1, B1
    2, B2
    4, B4
];

Left Join (Data)
LOAD
    X,
    if(IsNull(NewY), 'OffList', 'OnList') as Status
Resident Data;

DROP FIELD NewY;

LOAD
    *,
    'NewToList' as Status
WHERE Not Exists(X);
LOAD * INLINE [
    X, Y
    2, B2
    3, B3
    4, B3
];
```

Now a step by step explanation :

- Load the original table
- Load the second version of the table, with a left join, which will add new columns to the right of the existing one. X will be the same column on both tables, so it will link the same record in the first one with the same record on the second one. You'll need to rename Y, otherwise it will also be used as a key joining the tables.
- Taking the table Key, do a new Left Join, this time evaluating what you have on the NewY column. If it's null, means that is a new record. If it's filled, already existed. First stage of classification is complete.
- You can drop NewY, you don't need it anymore.
- Load again the second version of the table, making sure to load only entries that don't exist already (Exists(X)). If you are loading only the new ones, you can state that the status of this ones will be NewToList for sure.

Hope this helps, and that this can be seen as an "easy" solution.

Comment: That clarifies the joins required using the sample data, thank you very much. However, in the actual data, Y represents multiple fields, and renaming each would be a lot of effort. I achieved much the same result using the following script;

Comment: You don't need to rename all the columns on the left join, you'll need only to load the key columns on the most recent table plus on extra column, which will allow you to test of the record is null or not.